# ASP.NET client side validation script not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to build a web application using ASP.NET.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The above code is for a textbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function validate2() {
         if (document.getElementById("<%=textBoxToolID.ClientID%>").textContent=="") {
             alert('textbox1 cannot be empty');
             return false;
         }
     }
</script>
```

The above is the code I used for client side validation of null textbox.

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonNew" runat="server" Text="New" Width="75px" OnClick="buttonNew_Click" OnClientClick="validate()" />
```

I'm calling onclientclick property to call the validate function at the time of button click event.
The problem is even there is content in the textbox, the alert message is triggered.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: its `.value` not textContent`

Comment: document.getElementById("<%=textBoxToolID.ClientID%>").value

Comment: Independent of the  `.value` issue - you're returning `false` from the function, but you're not telling the button.  You also need to add `return` to become `OnClientClick="return validate()"`

Comment: Thanks that helped.  Just to gain more, what is the function of .textcontent or.tostring?  Other online material for the same didn't help me much.  If you anything about those, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validate2() {
     if (document.getElementById("<%=textBoxToolID.ClientID%>").value=="") {
         alert('textbox1 cannot be empty');
         return false;
     }
 }</script>
```

it's .value

Comment: Thank you.  It is working. the .value was not being shown by the intellisense, so I used .textcontent.  However out of curiosity, what does .textcontent do anyway?

Comment: Not sure but i believe the textcontent is used when the text parameter is used in your tag.. probably legacy stuff, if this provided you with the answer please accept as answer so others can find this

Answer (score 0):

asp.net has it's own Controls for validating user input. You might want to [read up on those](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/debza5t0.aspx).

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="textbox1 cannot be empty" ValidationGroup="myGroup1">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myGroup1" Text="Button 1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />



<asp:TextBox ID="textBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="textbox2 cannot be empty" ValidationGroup="myGroup2">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myGroup2" Text="Button 2" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

Comment: I tried that already but it keeps getting validated all the time.  Means I have no control over when this validation event fires.  Wherever I click on the web page, this event gets fired.  If you know how to control this event using a button share the details.  Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you were looking for `ValidationGroup`, That you can use to separate multiple validators and inputs on the same page.